# Clicking on the link is not triggering the action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am beginner in ruby on rails. I am building a movie review app for practising ruby on rails. In that application I am adding voting feature for movies (upvote and downvote).

Movies#index

```
<%= link_to "Add movie", new_movie_path %>
  <% @movies.each do |movie| %>
    <%= image_tag movie.thumbnail.url(:medium) %>
    <%= link_to movie.title, movie_path(movie) %>
    <%= link_to "upvote", {controller: "votes", action: "upvote"} %>
    <%= link_to "downvote",{controller:"votes", action: "downvote"} %>
  <% end %>
```

Votes controller

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def upvote
    Movie.find(params[:id]).vote.upvote += 1
    redirect_to movies_path
  end

  def downvote
    Movie.find(params[:id]).vote.downvote += 1
    redirect_to movies_path
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do    
  resources :movies    
  resources :votes
  root 'movies#index'  
end
```

When I click on the links ***upvote*** and ***downvote***(movies#index), the upvote and downvote actions are not triggering. It is throwing error

> No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"votes"}

Comment: `upvote` is not an action defined by default. You'll need to declare it manually, or use `create` instead.

Comment: I am not using acts_as_votable. I generated Vote model with :upvote and :downvote columns

Comment: I'm not sure how that's relevant. `resources` declares the usual REST actions, and `upvote` is not one of them.

Comment: how can I use the url in the link to trigger upvote action? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a resource definition for movies only and in addition two routes for upvote and downvote a movie:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :votes do
    member do
      get 'upvote'
      get 'downvote'
    end
  end
end
```

If you run `rake routes` now you get a nice list of routes to manage your movies and in addition the two more routes. All paths are processed in different actions of one controller.

```
~/dev/rubyonrails/test_app$rake routes
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action 
  upvote_movie GET    /movies/:id/upvote(.:format)   movies#upvote
downvote_movie GET    /movies/:id/downvote(.:format) movies#downvote
        movies GET    /movies(.:format)              movies#index
               POST   /movies(.:format)              movies#create
     new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)          movies#new
    edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)     movies#edit
         movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)          movies#show
               PATCH  /movies/:id(.:format)          movies#update
               PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)          movies#update
               DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)          movies#destroy
~/dev/rubyonrails/test_app$
```

Now you can use the route helpers (see Prefix in the list):

```
<%= link_to "upvote", upvote_movie_path(movie) %>
<%= link_to "down vote", downvote_movie_path(movie) %>
```

The `movie` object brings the `:id` attribute in the route paths, so you know which movie should be up or down voted.

**Note** the words of the router helper names. These sound like that what you want to do: upvote movie or downvote movie

Answer (score 2):

Your "votes_controller.rb" has defined MoviesController. Is it a typo ?

Also you need to define your custom resource routes. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more about routing in rails

I would also suggest you create a Vote model use

```
resources :votes
```

Vote model will have:
id: int
type: string
movie_id: int

And in view:

```
link_to 'Upvote', vote_path(movie_id: movie.id, type: 'up'), method: post
link_to 'Downvote', vote_path(movie_id: 42, type: 'down'), method: post
```

I am maybe mistaking the auto-generated path methods; to see all available routes from your app, open a terminal, navigate to your rails root folder and run:
     rake routes

All is explained in the link above

Comment: I now realized that you don't define the routes for custom actions.

Comment: That is because you don't pass any params when defining link. Updating answer

Comment: oh thanks I am able to see the route names by following your format. And can I pass parameters through link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103133/discussion-between-akash-pinnaka-and-doru-pirvu).